# Selecionando conjuntos de valores JPA

Tags: oracle, jpa, select, group-by

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu possuo uma tabela com uma lista de valores para uma uma chave composta. Segue exemplo:

```
ID | ItemCode | Localidade | Preco
---+----------+------------+-------
01 |      001 |        001 |   3.5
02 |      002 |        001 |   4.5
03 |      001 |        002 |   5.5
04 |      001 |        003 |   5.0
05 |      003 |        002 |  15.3
06 |      002 |        001 |   4.2
07 |      001 |        001 |   5.3
```

O que eu preciso é "agrupar" com base na combinação das colunas ItemCode e Localidade. Porem eu preciso utilizar a coluna Preco para fazer uma série de cálculos. A questão é que o GROUP BY não permite essa listagem, a coluna Preco deve ser incluída em uma função de agregação como por exemplo: SUM() ou AVG(). Como fazer para listar todos os preços de um determinado item e localidade. Considerando que eu não sei os valores em nenhuma das colunas e preciso utilizar todos os registros, sempre selecionando todos os registros para cada ItemCode e Localidade.

O retorno que eu desejo seria assim:

```
ItemCode | Localidade | Preco
---------+------------+-------
     001 |        001 |   [3.5, 5.3]
     001 |        002 |   [5.5]
     001 |        003 |   [5.0]
     002 |        001 |   [4.5, 4.2]
     003 |        002 |   [15.3]
```

Não sei se é possível fazer isso pelo JPA. Acho que vou ter que ordenar pelas duas colunas e percorrer o ResultSet pra montar o array.

Comment: Caro, como você precisa que este select retorne as linhas ? agrupamento de itemcode e localidade mostrando os preço na mesma linha ? ou mostrando cada preço por linha ?

Comment: @devgaspa Editei a pergunta pra explicar melhor o que desejo como resultado.

Comment: Mesma situação que a sua: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349598/how-to-aggregate-strings-with-jpa talvez ajude em algo.